# Error in BIO read. Program will now exit

Tags: events, notifications, messagebox

A message box periodically pops up with the title "Event Notification Application" and the text "Error in BIO read. Program will now exit"

Can anyone tell me what this error message is about? It occurs in a production environment and I have no idea where it's comming from.

Any clues very much appreciated!

Comment: Open Task Manager while the error message is shown, then "go to process" on the error window line in "Applications".

Comment: This doesn't really sounds programming related.

Comment: @Bemrose It might not be, but I have to know regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this error message on an IBM xSeries and it was caused by the LSI MegaRAID Storage software. Use Process Explorer and check the properties of the pop up.

Comment: Correct. That was the case here.

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually `BIO_read` (with underscore), then it would be related to [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_read.html). Of course, whoever put the message there might have dropped the underscore - so I'd look for applications using the OpenSSL DLLs (libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to diagnose these issues before: start it when the message is showing, click the bullseye icon on the toolbar and hold it down, then drag over and release when the bullseye is on the target window.  The process will be highlighted in the main program area.  Also, check your Application event log for errors, and see if you have any services that are set for automatic startup that are not running after you close the error dialog.

For what it's worth, I'd bet this issue is related to an auto-updater for some software installed on your machine.  Try to identify those auto-update services (I bet McAfee has one) and disable them for a time (if that's safe.)  Only disable one at a time so you can be reasonably sure which one the culprit is; be sure to enable it if it is ruled out.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have norton installed? It seems to be related to Norton 2000's live update.
Try disabling that and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Don't think so. McAffee, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was some raid software.